# ASP.NET Core return View navigate to anchor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

At the end of my controller method, I am returning a view with a viewmodel

```
return View(viewModel);
```

This works fine and opens the corresponding view.

I now want to jump to an anchor which I normally can by adding `#myanchor` to the URL. But I couldn't find a way to do this via the `return View(...);`.

Is this somehow possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using View(), however there is another solution.
Create a viewbag just before, and assign it anchor value :

```
ViewBag.AnchorValue = "#myanchor";
return View(viewModel);
```

Then, in your front view

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var anchor = document.getElementById('@Viewbag.AnchorValue');
    anchor.scrollIntoView(true);
});
```